# Get for each row of list-column the length

Tags: r, list, data.table

**Problem:** I want to find out the number of elements in a list-column (here `y`). Is there a more efficient and elegant way to determine this rather with `purrr::map`-function? This is really slow when trying to apply this to a data.table object with more than 700,000 rows.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  x = seq(4),
  y = list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 3), c(5, 1), c(12, 90, 200))
)

dt[, class(y)]

## more efficient/elegant way?
dt[, purrr::map(y, length)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
dt[, lengths(y)]

[1] 3 2 2 3
```